# Redirect the URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a page showing the products with the hyperlink for it as

```
 www.domainname.com/productname
```

now my client needs to add **store** and needs the URL to show as

```
 www.domainname.com/store/productname
```

I have done it via code and now when I click on it for a detail page, its still redirecting to

```
 www.domainname.com/productname
```

but need to be

```
 www.domainname.com/store/productname
```

tried with this: `RewriteRule ^store/?$ domina.com/?$ [NC,L]` in .htaccess file, not sure whether I'm on page

Can any one tell me how to do it via .htaccess file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: tried with this, RewriteRule    ^store/?$    http://domina.com/?$    [NC,L]

not sure whether I'm on the page or not.

Comment: Post this to your question.

Comment: done @Starkeen, if you have any clue please post.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
RewriteRule ^store/(.*)/?$ http://domain.com/store/$1 [R,L,NC]
```

Comment: tried it, but doesn't work

URL is http://www.domainname.com/store/ebay/

and it says, The page isn't redirecting properly